# Почему не работает сортировка datagrid c#?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, сортировка, datagrid

Есть таблица DataGrid. Подключил к ней json файл с данными, все показывает и работает. Пытался сделать сортировку а-я по нажатию на заголовок таблицы. Вроде все есть, но не сортирует. В чем проблема?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridView1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Margin="0,34,8,119" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" Grid.Column="1">
           <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Namee}" Header="Name" Width="145" CanUserSort="True" SortDirection="Ascending" SortMemberPath="Namee" />
               <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Symptoms}" Header="Symptoms" Width="145" CanUserSort="True" />
               <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Procedures}" Header="Procedures" Width="145" CanUserSort="True" />
               <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Recommended}" Header="Recommended medicines" Width="*" CanUserSort="True" />
           </DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGrid.RowStyle>
               <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                   <Style.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                       </Trigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
           </DataGrid.RowStyle>
       </DataGrid>
```

```
 private readonly string Path = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\Dannie.json";
        private BindingList<Model> Dannie;
        private SaveFile saveFile;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            saveFile = new SaveFile(Path);

            try
            {
                Dannie = saveFile.Load();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); //если ошибка, приложение закрывается
                Close();
            }


            DataGridView1.ItemsSource = Dannie;
            Dannie.ListChanged += Dannie_ListChanged;

        }
```

Comment: А как вы пытаетесь сортировать? Вижу у вас BindingList, который, как я понимаю, привязывается к DataGridView для отображения данных. В чём возникает проблема?

Comment: да вроде бы не могёт биндинглист сам сортировать, надо извращаться
один из вариантов - прописать через linq и дергать

Comment: Вместо `BindingList<T>` попробуйте `ObservableCollection<T>`.